# Need help regarding to E-Commerce website using PHP?

Tags: php, html, e-commerce

Greetings, 
I have a file hosting website like rapidshre, I want to make it E-Commerce website.
I am using PHP as a scripting language. Can somebody helps me or suggest me good resources to learn how can I add E-Commerce functionality in my website??

Thank you

Comment: Googling "php e-commerce" will give you some starting points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy [This](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-PHP-MySQL--Commerce-Professional/dp/1590598644/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1296817183&sr=8-4) and never look back.

I used this on my very first PHP E-Commerce project, that project got zipped up and sent off to a potential employer where I then worked for two years.

I am sure there are plenty of we resources out there but there is nothing like learning from a book to get you into it.